# Segfault from std::getline with delimiter

Tags: c++, csv, segmentation-fault

For hours, I have been trying to fix this segfault. This code always sends SIGSEGV after the 500th iteration. [Here's the TEST.csv I've been using](http://pastebin.com/fpb6T9E5). Once the while loop hits the second set of AMU values, getline immediately crashes the program. I've combed over this and cannot find the issue to save my life.

WORTH NOTING: I can't reproduce this error on every machine! Definitely some memory getting mangled somewhere but I just can't figure it out!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <climits>
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    ifstream data;
    data.open("TEST.csv", ifstream::in);
    float amudata[505];
    //initialize amudata
    for (int x = 0; x < 505; x++) amudata[x] = INT_MIN;
    std::string line;
    //toss out the first 137 lines of config data
    for (int x = 0; x < 137; x++)
    {
        std::getline(data, line);
    }
    //debug iteration counter
    int x = 0;
    //toss out the first part of the timestamp
    //this is where SEGV happens
    while (std::getline(data, line, ' '))
    {
        x++;
        //toss out second part of timestamp
        getline(data, line, ',');
        //read and store the index, which is amu times 10
        std::getline(data, line, ',');
        int index = std::atof(line.c_str()) * 10;
        //read and store the amu intensity
        std::getline(data, line, ',');
        float intensity = std::atof(line.c_str());
        //some debug output
        cout << index << " " << intensity << " ";
        cout << line << " " << x << endl;
        //keep track of only the maximum intensities
        if (amudata[index] < intensity) 
        {
            amudata[index] = intensity;
        }
    }
    for (int x = 0; x < 505; x++)
    {
        printf("%f\n", amudata[x]);
    }
    data.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: No. Do not use `std::getline()` to try to parse XML. The code is not doing bounds checking at all, and it's a near certainty that at some point this is going to parse what it's not intended to parse, run off the end of the array, and clobber memory. This whole thing cannot be salvaged. Scrap it, and start over from scratch, using a proper XML parsing library.

Comment: Did you know your `csv` data is preceded of a bunch of `XML`?

Comment: Did you miss the part where 99% of this file is CSV, and all the XML data is tossed out as soon as its opened?

Comment: Unrelated: any reason why your `main` isn't indented?

Comment: @qxz paste formatting issues I suppose, it was originally indented

Comment: Is the segfault coming from `getline` or some function of `ifstream data`? Any additional debugger data you have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `amudata` array is too small.

Your program crashes after you process this line:

```
2016/11/23 16:49:06.146,   50.500, -3.6263e-010,
```

When you do:

```
int index = std::atof(line.c_str()) * 10;
```

`line` is `"50.500"`, so this sets `index = 505`. Then you do:

```
amudata[index] = intensity;
```

But the allowable indexes of `amudata` are from `0` to `504`, so you're writing outside the array bounds, which causes undefined behavior.

You need:

```
float amudata[506];
//initialize amudata
for (int x = 0; x < 506; x++) amudata[x] = INT_MIN;
```

And it's best not to spread magic numbers like that around in the program, use a constant or macro.